# libvirt - ssh into qemu/kvm host from Fedora 23

Tags: ssh, fedora, linux-kvm, qemu, libvirt

I would like to ssh into a qemu/kvm host from my Fedora 23 host. They are on the local network, but I can't figure out how to ssh into them from the same machine. I read this: http://davidz25.blogspot.com/2012/06/authorization-rules-in-polkit.html, but it didn't seem to indicate or show an example of setting it up so I could access my virtual machines from ssh.

Comment: Are you saying `ssh <ip address of machine>` doesn't work from the host machine but does work from other machines on the network?

Comment: `ssh` doesn't really care whether you're connecting to a physical machine or a virtual one, so just try to connect as you would with any other host

Comment: I just used the IP address and connected like any other host, thanks @EricRenouf